# Count variables in fitted model within R

Tags: r

I am simply trying to count the number of independent variables have been used to fit a model in R. I have been playing around using different number of predictors and want to pass the number of predictors used to a value which I use later on in my code.

I have been using the longley dataset to fit a model:

```
fit<- lm(Employed~., longley)
```

I can easily visualize the number of variables ie 6 via `summary(fit)` used but as stated I want to store the value

Comment: `summary(fit)$df[1] - 1` can be used to see the number of estimated betas, not including the intercept, in the fitted model.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `str(fit)` you can see all of the information stored in `fit`.  The number of coefficients - 1 (for the intercept) should work to give you the number of predictors.  Or, you can get this information from the model.  Here is one way

```
data(longley)
fit<- lm(Employed~., longley)

attr(fit$terms, "term.labels")
# [1] "GNP.deflator" "GNP"          "Unemployed"   "Armed.Forces" "Population"  
# [6] "Year"        

## Number of predictors
length(coef(fit))-1  #-1 for intercept
```

Comment: Beware, if the model has categorical variables with more than two levels, the number of coefficients is not equal to the number of predictors. In that case, `length(attr(fit$terms, "term.labels"))` will do the trick.